# Does criteria.List(Type) transaction management

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, transactions, icriteria

Does this (not CRUD, but only Read) code require me to write transaction management?

```
ICriteria criteria = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession().CreateCriteria(EntityType);
criteria.List<BaseEntity>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say that I do it always, But I would say that this question is pretty reasonable. As you can [Transactions for read-only DB access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818074/1679310) what we can get is:

> Transaction are required for read-only operations if you want to set a specific timeout for queries other than the default timeout, or if you want to change the isolation level.

And as mentioned here: [NHibernate Transactions on Reads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1657465/1679310) (small extract)

> Even if we are only reading data, we want to use a transaction, because using a transaction ensure that we get a consistent result from the database.

So, in general, if you have common way (e.g. Web request handling with AOP) it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

No, why would you need a transaction for read only operations?

Transactions are only needed if you want to rollback multiple write/update/delete operations.