# Do I need to add CommitChange() in each Save, SaveOrUpdate and Delete Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, commit

I have started to implement an asp.net webpage using `NHibernate` as a Database Mapping.

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13390/NHibernate-Best-Practices-with-ASP-NET-nd-Ed), but I am having trouble getting the code to work.

The following is my script that I have modified in an abstract class.

Could you please let me know if the modification is correct?

I have added method `this.CommitChanges();` to all `Save`, `SaveOrUpdate`, and `Delete` method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Criterion;
using Tec.Core.DataInterfaces;
using Tec.Data.SessionManagement;



    namespace Tec.Data
    {
        public abstract class NHibernateRepository<T, IdT> : IRepository<T, IdT>
        {
            public T GetById(IdT id, bool shouldLock)
            {
                T entity;

                if (shouldLock)
                {
                    entity = (T)NHibernateSession.Load(persitentType, id, LockMode.Upgrade);
                }
                else
                {
                    entity = (T)NHibernateSession.Load(persitentType, id);
                }

                return entity;
            }


            public List<T> GetAll()
            {
                return GetByCriteria();
            }


            public List<T> GetByCriteria(params ICriterion[] criterion)
            {
                ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persitentType);

                foreach (ICriterion criterium in criterion)
                {
                    criteria.Add(criterium);
                }

                return criteria.List<T>() as List<T>;
            }

            public List<T> GetByExample(T exampleInstance, params string[] propertiesToExclude)
            {
                ICriteria criteria = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(persitentType);
                Example example = Example.Create(exampleInstance);

                foreach (string propertyToExclude in propertiesToExclude)
                {
                    example.ExcludeProperty(propertyToExclude);
                }

                criteria.Add(example);

                return criteria.List<T>() as List<T>;
            }


            public T GetUniqueByExample(T exampleInstance, params string[] propertiesToExclude)
            {
                List<T> foundList = GetByExample(exampleInstance, propertiesToExclude);

                if (foundList.Count > 1)
                {
                    throw new NonUniqueResultException(foundList.Count);
                }

                if (foundList.Count > 0)
                {
                    return foundList[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    return default(T);
                }
            }


            public T Save(T entity) {
                NHibernateSession.Save(entity);
                //this.CommitChanges(); // manually added
                return entity;
            }


            public T SaveOrUpdate(T entity)
            {
                NHibernateSession.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
                //this.CommitChanges(); 
                return entity;
            }

            public void Delete(T entity) {
                NHibernateSession.Delete(entity);
                //this.CommitChanges(); //Record is delete from database only if I enable this
                                        statement           
            }


            public void CommitChanges(){
                if (NHibernateSessionFactory.Instance.HasOpenTransaction()) {
                    NHibernateSessionFactory.Instance.CommitTransaction();
                } else {
                    // If there's no transaction, just flush the changes
                    NHibernateSessionFactory.Instance.GetSession().Flush();
                }
            }


            private ISession NHibernateSession
            {
                get
                {
                    return NHibernateSessionFactory.Instance.GetSession();
                }
            }

            private Type persitentType = typeof(T);
        }




        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//




        public class NHibernateSessionFactory
        {
            public static NHibernateSessionFactory Instance
            {
                get
                {
                    return Nested.NHibernateSessionFactory;
                }
            }


            private NHibernateSessionFactory()
            {
                InitSessionFactory();
            }


            private class Nested
            {
                static Nested() { }
                internal static readonly NHibernateSessionFactory NHibernateSessionFactory = new NHibernateSessionFactory();
            }



            private void InitSessionFactory()
            {
                sessionFactory = new Configuration().Configure().BuildSessionFactory();
            }


            public void RegisterInterceptor(IInterceptor interceptor)
            {
                ISession session = ContextSession;
                if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
                {
                    throw new CacheException("You cannot register an interceptor once a session has already been opened");
                }
                GetSession(interceptor);
            }

            public ISession GetSession()
            {
                return GetSession(null);
            }


            private ISession GetSession(IInterceptor interceptor)
            {
                ISession session = ContextSession;
                if (session == null)
                {
                    if (interceptor != null)
                    {
                        session = sessionFactory.OpenSession(interceptor);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
                    }
                    ContextSession = session;
                }
                return session;
            }


            public void CloseSession()
            {
                ISession session = ContextSession;
                if (session != null && session.IsOpen)
                {
                    session.Flush();
                    session.Close();
                }
                ContextSession = null;
            }

            public void BeginTransaction()
            {
                ITransaction transaction = ContextTransaction;
                if (transaction == null)
                {
                    transaction = GetSession().BeginTransaction();
                    ContextTransaction = transaction;
                }
            }

            public void CommitTransaction()
            {
                ITransaction transaction = ContextTransaction;
                try
                {
                    if (HasOpenTransaction())
                    {
                        transaction.Commit();
                        ContextTransaction = null;
                    }
                }
                catch (HibernateException)
                {
                    RollbackTransaction();
                    throw;
                }
            }

            public bool HasOpenTransaction()
            {
                ITransaction transaction = ContextTransaction;
                return transaction != null && !transaction.WasCommitted && !transaction.WasRolledBack;
            }

            public void RollbackTransaction()
            {
                ITransaction transaction = ContextTransaction;

                try
                {
                    if (HasOpenTransaction())
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                    }
                    ContextTransaction = null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    CloseSession();
                }
            }


            private ITransaction ContextTransaction
            {
                get
                {
                    if (IsInWebContext())
                    {
                        return (ITransaction)HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (ITransaction)CallContext.GetData(TRANSACTION_KEY);
                    }
                }
                set
                {
                    if (IsInWebContext())
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Items[TRANSACTION_KEY] = value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CallContext.SetData(TRANSACTION_KEY, value);
                    }
                }
            }


            private ISession ContextSession
            {
                get
                {
                    if (IsInWebContext())
                    {
                        return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (ISession)CallContext.GetData(SESSION_KEY);
                    }
                }
                set
                {
                    if (IsInWebContext())
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY] = value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CallContext.SetData(SESSION_KEY, value);
                    }
                }
            }

            private bool IsInWebContext()
            {
                return HttpContext.Current != null;
            }

            private const string TRANSACTION_KEY = "CONTEXT_TRANSACTION";
            private const string SESSION_KEY = "CONTEXT_SESSION";
            private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        }


    }
```

Here is my test method:

```
public void AddUser()
{
   // create three people
   User jose = new User();
   jose.UserName = "Jose";
   jose.UserLogin = "28";
   mUser.SaveOrUpdate(jose);// Record is addded to database, 
                            // some people said it's 
                            // because on auto-increment identity 

   User maria = new User();
   maria.UserName = "Maria";
   maria.UserLogin = "29";
   mUser.SaveOrUpdate(maria);

   User mario = new User();
   mario.UserName = "Mario";
   mario.UserLogin = "27";
   mUser.SaveOrUpdate(mario);

   // delete Mario
   mUser.Delete(mario); //Record is not deleted from database
}
```

and I got only these 3 statement execute on SQL profiler

```
exec sp_reset_connection
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO TEC.dbo.tblSysUser (UserName, UserLogin) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Jose',@p1=N'28'
exec sp_reset_connection
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO TEC.dbo.tblSysUser (UserName, UserLogin) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Maria',@p1=N'29'
exec sp_reset_connection
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO TEC.dbo.tblSysUser (UserName, UserLogin) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Mario',@p1=N'27'
```

Statement after un-comment this.CommitChanges() on Delete Methode

```
exec sp_reset_connection
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO TEC.dbo.tblSysUser (UserName, UserLogin) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Jose',@p1=N'28'
exec sp_reset_connection
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO TEC.dbo.tblSysUser (UserName, UserLogin) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Maria',@p1=N'29'
exec sp_reset_connection
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO TEC.dbo.tblSysUser (UserName, UserLogin) VALUES (@p0, @p1); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'Mario',@p1=N'27'
exec sp_reset_connection
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM TEC.dbo.tblSysUser WHERE UserID = @p0',N'@p0 bigint',@p0=64
```

Could you please advise what is going on in my code? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

I would say: **The code, shown in the question, is resulting in a wrong, undesired results.** But the issue is not on the NHibernate side *(e.g. some bug in implementation)*.

The problem is, that each operation set *(web-request, unit of work)* should be encapsulated in a **transcation** - with explicit `Commit` or `Rollback` call.

NHibernate sometimes simply must execute some WRITE operation statments *(cite from [9.6. Flush](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing) documentation:)

> ... **objects using native ID generation are inserted when they are saved** ...

The fact that NHibernate must issue that call, does not mean, that such operation should persist. In this case, it is only the result of inevitable - to get DB generated ID. It still could happen, that we should rollback operation later...

The most important setting is a `FlushMode` of a `ISession` *(cite from [9.6. Flush](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing) documentation:)

> ... Except when you explicity `Flush()`, there are absolutely no guarantees about when the Session executes the ADO.NET calls, only the order in which they are executed. *However, NHibernate does guarantee that the `ISession.Find(..)` methods will never return stale data; nor will they return the wrong data.*

So, exactly what we have experienced above - FlushMode set to Auto...no explicit transaction Commit or Rollback, but data are persisted. **But it was most likely the accident ...** because of missing transaction

#### FlushMode

Here are available [FlushModes](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/FlushMode.cs) *(see cite, code snippet below)*

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a flushing strategy.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The flush process synchronizes database state with session state by detecting state
/// changes and executing SQL statements
/// </remarks>
[Serializable]
public enum FlushMode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Special value for unspecified flush mode (like <see langword="null" /> in Java).
    /// </summary>
    Unspecified = -1,

    /// <summary>
    /// The <c>ISession</c> is never flushed unless <c>Flush()</c> is explicitly
    /// called by the application. This mode is very efficient for read only
    /// transactions
    /// </summary>
    Never = 0,
    /// <summary>
    /// The <c>ISession</c> is flushed when <c>Transaction.Commit()</c> is called
    /// </summary>
    Commit = 5,
    /// <summary>
    /// The <c>ISession</c> is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to
    /// ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.
    /// </summary>
    Auto = 10,
    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="ISession"/> is flushed before every query. This is
    /// almost always unnecessary and inefficient.
    /// </summary>
    Always = 20
}
```

When we are creating a Session from a Factory, we can assign one of these FlushModes. **I would strongly sugges to use the `FlushMode.Commit`** or - use the FlusMode.Never and call the Session.Flush() just before the transaction Commit().

Because - we should be the driver of the explicit call to `Flush()`. So, do not rely on the fact, that NHiberante issued the INSERT. It was a must for later processing. Always wrap the set of operations in Transacton, use FlushMode.Commit... that would be my suggestion

*NOTE: Also check this [Does criteria.List(Type) transaction management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20679126/), for more links discussing the advantage of transactions even for read operations.*

Comment: So from your idea, I should un-comment this.CommitChange() on those definition of Save, SaveOrUpdate, and Delete Methode?

Comment: Think about the fact, that it is working without the explicit Commit as **accident**. That would be my suggestion. It is wrong, because we did not ask, NHibernate to do that: 1) nor by calling Flush() or Commit() 2) neither by Setting Session.FlushMode to always. That means ... because NHibernate needed to do INSERT (to recieve ID) it is wrong... unless complete operation is executed as well. We should use transaction per request or unit of work. But only complete (and completely succesful) operation should end in Flush() and Commit(). Does it help a bit?

Comment: I am not really get your points, Radim Köhler. You mean that, record should not be persistent to database unless we explicit calling Flush() or Commit() event it's an identity? I might make you some headache, because I am very new to these technology that's why I try to search for a proper implementation using them.

Comment: I tried to explain it from a different angle. The point, the main point is: what you've experienced is not what you should want. It was just a must... which ended in the INSERT.

Comment: It would be very great if I would have a small and complete implementation using these base on C#, ASP.NET

Comment: Check for example this. It is exactly what you can start with http://pwigle.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/nhibernate-session-handling-in-aspnet-the-easy-way/

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. NHibernate is great tool, would be shame to not make it running ;)